# Full-disk encryption without reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, disk-encryption

I’m looking for some best practices for full-disk encryption (without having to reinstall Windows).

Is it possible to encrypt only user profiles? What tools are necessary? Can I encrypt a whole drive with Bitlocker Truecrypt without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Bitlocker works without reinstalling Windows, but is only part of Win7(8 Enterprise. You need to post more details about which Windows you use. Truecrypt works for all Windows versions, but I never used it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 BitLocker supports Windows 8 Pro, too...

Comment: What if we're talking about Windows 7 (not Enterprise or Ultimate)?

Answer (score 1):

I use True Crypt on my work laptop.  Just install the software, fire up the wizard, and tell it you want to encrypt your entire drive. Let it run for a few hours (depending on the speed and size of the disk), and you're good to go.